# Could redundant Sass selectors be causing a performance hit in a typical use case?

Tags: css, sass, compression, gzip

This is a question I feel like I already know the answer to, but I'm asking to reconfirm.

Use of nesting in Sass results in some redundant selectors, but I believe compression makes this a non-issue.

Consider the following Sass output:

```
.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion .exact-container.container.ex-container-fixed .accordion .items .toggle-content .promo .text p:first-of-type .ex-icon-plus {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion .exact-container.container.ex-container-fixed .accordion .items .toggle-content .promo .text p:first-of-type .ex-icon-minus {
    min-height: 50px;
}

.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion .exact-container.container.ex-container-fixed .accordion .items .toggle-content .promo .text p:first-of-type .ex-icon-multiply {
    margin-top: 20px
}

.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion .exact-container.container.ex-container-fixed .accordion .items .toggle-content .promo .text p:first-of-type .ex-icon-multiply:before {
    font-size: 54px
}

.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion .exact-container.container.ex-container-fixed .accordion .items .toggle-content .promo .text p:first-of-type .ex-icon-question img {
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0
}
```

When you learn about compression, it's the first concept you have to understand, that any redundant string of characters will get replaced by a shorter string, and the original swapped back in at decompression...

And if compression is enabled as it should be in production on the server (and I know it is in this case), the redundant selectors resulting from Sass nesting should have negligible weight on file size, right?

Am I missing anything here?

I'm asking because I think I am being asked to refactor Sass to reduce redundant selectors in Sass output. If I'm right, then there is very little to be gained from that.

It could be that decompression could take more time, but it seems like that also should be negligible unless there is an excessive amount of this.

Am I right on my thought process here? The main question is to do with the compression from the server, which is gzip.

@cs.matyi's answer here is helpful indeed, but it does not answer my main question about gzip compression from the server. I'm wondering if compression makes refactoring our SASS a waste of time compared to other optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you define "negligible", nor "reasonably negligible". It is true that repeated strings like that will be greatly reduced in size by gzip. But not to nothing. I compressed your example, and if I remove gzip and deflate headers and trailers (since they would be a smaller fraction of the total for a more realistic, larger input), the 1024 bytes were reduced to 167 bytes. The first line took 102 bytes, and the subsequent lines took 12 to 22 bytes each.

Here is a disassembly of the compressed data, where each "match x y" line says to copy x bytes starting from y bytes back:

```
literal '.ease-of-use .ex-snippet-icon-left-with-accordion
match 4 37
literal 'act-
match 3 31
literal 'tainer.
match 10 10
match 3 63
match 9 13
literal '-fixed .
match 11 57
literal 'items .toggle
match 5 42
literal 'ent .promo
match 3 23
literal 'ext p:first
match 4 145
literal 'typ
match 6 146
match 5 138
literal 'plus {
literal 10 ' 
match 3 1
literal 'margin-top: 15px;
literal 10 '}
literal 10 10 '.
match 167 200
literal 'min
match 10 201
match 3 198
literal 'height: 50
match 176 201
literal 'ultiply
match 19 405
literal '2
match 3 204
match 180 203
literal ':before
match 7 210
literal 'f
match 3 68
literal '-size
match 3 413
literal '4
match 174 209
literal 'quest
match 4 70
literal 'img
match 13 416
match 3 412
match 3 203
literal ' 0 12
match 4 7
match 3 212
```

Comment: As for "negligible", I'm weighing  prioritization of SASS or other areas to optimize first. I could spend days refactoring SASS and testing, or I can spend the time elsewhere. So yeah, it's relative. Is there to say if this is typical of gzip from a server? Without digging into the issue, I've read there are options for how to gzip.

Comment: Yes, it's the same gzip. The only options are the compression level. I selected the highest level for that output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the shared code snippet what you provided, it could impact the performance if there are a lot of redundant css selectors. Sure when your compiler compress this code you will win a lot in the generated file size and the browser will load the provided css faster.

In my opinion deeply nested classes will be hard to maintain on the long term. 
According to the [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules) documentation, if you have to nest classes more then 3 level, you should consider to rethink your html/css structure.

> Nested rules are super helpful, but they can also make it hard to visualize how much CSS you’re actually generating. The deeper you nest, the more bandwidth it takes to serve your CSS and the more work it takes the browser to render it. Keep those selectors shallow!

Hope it answered your question.

Comment: That is very helpful info, and will make it's way into my considerations, but as for my primary question, doesn't gzip from the server make the bandwidth factor reasonably negligible?